# Can AWS API Gateway route requests to different endpoints on the basis of a path variable value

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Let's consider this simple scenario for the AWS API Gateway.

I have a resource with a request path variable `/numbers/{id}` and two http endpoints: http://odd.number.io and http://even.number.io.

How can I setup AWS API Gateway to route requests to one or the other endpoint when the `id` is an odd or an even number?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible with API Gateway alone. You could proxy through a Lambda function where you can execute a logical decision, but API Gateway itself doesn't have support this kind of logical rule.